# Django tests parallel issues

Tags: django, unit-testing, parallel-processing

```
Django ver: 1.11.25
PostgreSQL ver: 11.5
```

So I'm having some issues trying to run my `django` tests in parallel. I've tried setting the `(--parallel)` flag, which is able to create copies of the test db, however it runs all of them under the main thread and doesn't create any other threads. My tests need to call the class's setUpClass to populate the databases up to a certain point, dump data into a fixture, and then each setUp they load data off that fixture (which is working correctly). The only problem I'm faced with is that it's all run sequentially instead of in parallel. I tried using `django-nose` (--processes) flag, but this simply runs my setUpClass per process, and it only creates the one test db for all the processes to share. My test class is a StaticLiveServerTestCase. Any info is appreciated!